# PayPal `rm` hidden value not returning POST data

Tags: post, methods, paypal, return, rm

```
<form action=" https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" id="paypalform" name="paypalform">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="abc@abc.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="<?php echo $currency ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" name="country" value="US">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://abc-return.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://abc-cancel.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Recharge">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number_1" value="<?php echo $user_id  ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="<?php echo $price ?>">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">document.paypalform.submit();</script>
```

I'm using PayPal Payments Standard, via the HTML hidden name-value pair.

Payment was working great and smooth as butter until the 9th of this month, when things started getting worse. The return method `rm = 2` was returning the post data to my return page before this date, but when I checked on 9th, the post data is not returning to my page.

I've spent more than a week and still can't figure out how could the same code works one day, and not the day afterwards.

I've implemented this method in my many other projects which could get me into trouble if the data is not posting back on my return page. Everything is just fine with my HTML forms, and I'm also receiving the payment on my PayPal Sandbox

The only issue is I'm not getting the post data on my return page.

Please help me resolve this.

Comment: When you say it's no longer returning **`POST`** data, what data are you expecting to get back? Have you set any data on the PayPal Payment itself? If so, have you debugged to confirm that the data still actually exists on the PayPal button in PayPal itself?

Comment: i'm expecting to get back data that are posted to paypal like  txn_id etc  and all other parameters

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I also confirm this issue.  I am not certain if this is a Paypal change or a Paypal error - for it is difficult to find authoritative answers from them.

I also have a form that used to return POST data to the return url - however it recently stopped working and I was able to get it working again using GET method instead by following [this helpful article.](https://www.codexworld.com/paypal-standard-payment-gateway-integration-php/comment-page-2/#comment-49250)

However, this will require some changes to your IPN and success pages.

Curious to know how you solved your issue. Please update us.

Comment: now things have started working for me. I've added another variable notify_url and provided the file path ( not the url) where i want to collect the $_POST.But you cannot get it instatntly. Simply check the txn_id and then perform the sql queries your data will be inserted. but you cannot echo $_POST.

Comment: How did they start working again? Are you now getting POST data to your return URL?  If you are, it should be fairly instant!  Please share what you did to start getting POST data again at the return URL.  I can only receive GET data !  Frustrated with PayPal.

Comment: yes i have started gettigback the post data simply go to your business acccount via paypal and in profile> instant payment notification turn on to receive ipn message and in the file url path just give your file path where you want the post data .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your update, however, I think there's some confusion here. The IPN url is called the notify_URL and that should receive the POSTed data back to verify the transaction.  The Thank you page (or success page) is called the return url - which is where your AutoReturn takes you.  I have always been receiving the POST data to my IPN page no problem AND the the POST data to my return URL.  However, just in the last few weeks, the POST data stopped coming to my success (return) URL but there's no explanation as to why it would suddenly stop.  Now, I can only receive GET data at my success/return page by turning on PDT.  But it's OK - I re-wrote my thank you page script to use the GET variables instead.  PayPal must have change this without there being any notification - very annoyed with them.